# Angular animation directive should call controller function after animation has finished

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to write an animation directive, that changes the width of an element and makes a change in the model afterwords. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
            <button ng-init="speed=20000" ng-click="model.width = model.width + 100;"> + </button>
            <button ng-click="model.width = model.width - 100;"> - </button>
            <div animate-to-width="model.width" speed="{{speed}}" done="model.done()" style="background-color: #f00; width: 100px;">w:{{model.width}}|a:{{model.a}}|b:{{model.b}}</div>
        </div>

        <script src="components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="components/angular-unstable/angular.js"></script>
        <script>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('animateToWidth', function() {
    return {
        'restrict': 'A',
        'link' : {
            'post': function(scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.$watch(
                    attrs.animateToWidth,
                    function (newValue) {
                        element.animate(
                            {'width': newValue + 'px'},
                            attrs.speed,
                            function () {
                                scope.model.a++;
                                //scope[attrs.done]();
                            }
                        );
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    };
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.model = {};
    $scope.model.width = 100;
    $scope.model.a = 0;
    $scope.model.b = 0;
    $scope.model.done = function () { $scope.model.b++; };
}

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run this code the second parameter of the jQuery .animate() function seems not to affect the animation speeds and the callback (third parameter) will be called immediately instead after the animation has been finished.

My second problem is, that I would want to pass a callback from the controller into the directive and I don't know how to achieve this.

**EDIT**

Here is the solution (thanks to [@banana-in-black](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19201651/angular-animation-directive-should-call-controller-function-after-animation-has/19202374#19202374)):

http://plnkr.co/edit/D9TJHBYjtnxTve0xZpBS?p=preview

And here without those width values in the controller:

http://plnkr.co/edit/eiy99Crh57Jc78RhAsRt?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you get from attrs.speed is `String`, and there's no effect if you set duration as `String` to `jQuery.animate()`. So make it a Number could solve the speed issue.

The callback after `jQuery.animate()` is called outside "the angular world", so you have to use [$apply](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply) to make sure angular knows what happened to models.

If you didn't assign scope to directive, it will use the existing scope on the element. In this case, the div[animate-to-width] uses the same scope as MyCtrl does. You can just call your function which is set to scope in your controller.

```
scope.$watch(
    attrs.animateToWidth,
    function (newValue) {
        element.animate(
            {'width': newValue + 'px'},
            attrs.speed * 1,
            function () {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    scope.model.a++;
                    scope.model.done();
                });
            }
        );
    }
);
```

[Example in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4nKqUZDUOIVI0wd2JFCl?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you! Making `speed` an integer solves the two problems, that `speed` has been ignored and the callback has been called immediately (not after the animation has been finished). I know about `$apply`, thank you. My problem here was, that the callback has been executed **immediately** and `a` has been incremented, although it has not been set into `$apply`. I don't want to hardcode the controller function call in the directive, because I don't want to let the directive know anything about the controller. But I solved the callback problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/D9TJHBYjtnxTve0xZpBS?p=preview